# How can I create a header without margin in pdf created with snappy twig (Symfony 4)?

Tags: php, css, symfony, pdf, snappy

I create a pdf in Symfony via snappy from a twig template:

So this is my Controller, where I am creating the pdf:

```
 /**
  * @Route("/pdf", name="pdf")
  */

  public function pdf(Request $request, Pdf $snappy)
  {

    $snappy->setOption("encoding","UTF-8");

    $html = $this->renderView("default/pdf.html.twig",array(
      "title" => "pdf"
    ));

    $filename = "mypdf";
    return new Response(
      $snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html),
      200,
      array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'.pdf"'
      )
    );

  }
```

And here is the html template, where I create the header
pdf.html.twig:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}



.header-right {
  float: right;
}


}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <a href="#default" class="logo">Logo</a>

</div>

<div style="padding-left:20px">
  <h1>headline</h1>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some content..</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I try that the black header fits into the page without border. But there is still a white border. It does not go to the edge.

Comment: Can you be more precise about the effects you see? Are you looking at a PDF document or the html in a browser? Is the white border related to `<div class="header">...` or to `<div style="padding-left:20px">...`?

Comment: @geoB I am looking at the pdf document, that I open in my browser. I don't know why there is a white border. I only want everything black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
 $snappy->setOption("encoding","UTF-8");
```

into

```
$snappy->setOption("encoding","UTF-8");
$snappy->setOption('margin-left', '0mm');
$snappy->setOption('margin-right', '0mm');
$snappy->setOption('margin-top', '0mm');
```

Comment: Glad you found a working alternative. I'd put mine in an environment variable to make it possible to do both Windows & Linux environments.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that wkhtmltopdf defaults to non-zero left & right margins. If you modify your executable to `wkhtmltopdf -R 0 -L 0 ...` the black will extend to the width of the page. See [this](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt).

Btw, you may want to remove the extra brace `}` at the line immediately above `</style>`

Comment: I tried to write in the line `wkhtmltopdf -R 0 -L 0` into the terminal and I get the message `You need to specify at least one input file, and exactly one output file
Use - for stdin or stdout`